# While having the lock screen set to delay, is it possible to lock a phone instantly (Galaxy S20 FE in particular)?

Tags: lock-screens

I like having my phone (GS 20 FE) not lock automatically for a while, but there are times when it would be nice to be able to lock it instantly.

Often, I'll turn my screen off, put my phone in my pocket, and when I take it back out a few minutes later, it'll be in a settings menu of some random app.  Or trying to send a message to a random contact.  Or asking if I really want to delete a file.

It would be nice to be able to lock my phone immediately before I put it in my pocket but keep it on the delay setting for when I'm sitting somewhere.

Does anyone know if there's an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Every Android phone I have ever used has had a button for that very purpose.  Why not use it?

Comment: Because turning the screen off and locking the phone aren't the same thing.  Sometimes they both happen when this button is used.  But since I have my phone set to delay locking for a little while, this button only serves to turn the screen off.